# FromUri does not seem to work Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement a search-filter for getting objects in one of my controllers.
I have the following code:

```
public class SearchFilter
{
    public DateTime? BusinessDate;
    public DateTime? BusinessDateFrom;
    public DateTime? BusinessDateTo;
    public bool? Status;
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
    public SearchFilter get([FromUri] SearchFilter SearchFilter)
    {
        var Results = db.MyTable.Where(t => t.Published == true);
        if (SearchFilter.BusinessDate != null)
        {
            Results = Results.Where(t => t.BusinessDate == SearchFilter.BusinessDate);
        }
        else
        {
            if (SearchFilter.BusinessDateFrom != null && SearchFilter.BusinessDateTo != null)
            {
                Results = Results.Where(t => t.BusinessDate >= SearchFilter.BusinessDateFrom && t.BusinessDate <= SearchFilter.BusinessDateTo);
            }
        }
        if (SearchFilter.Status != null)
        {
            Results = Results.Where(t => t.Approved == SearchFilter.Status);
        }

        return SearchFilter;
    }
```

I am now returning SearchFilter just to see if it is working, because the filtering was not working.

Here is why:

Request to: `http://localhost:11513/api/MyController/?BusinessDateFrom=2015-09-10&BusinessDateTo=2015-09-12&BusinessDate=09/09/2015&Status=true`
results in:

```
{
  "BusinessDate": null,
  "BusinessDateFrom": null,
  "BusinessDateTo": null,
  "Status": null
}
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong, because according to this link it should be pretty straight forward:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized what the problem was.

The problem was in the SearchFilter class, it was lacking `get` and `set` for each property.

```
public class SearchFilter
{
    public DateTime? BusinessDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BusinessDateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BusinessDateTo { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
}
```

This made it work like a charm.

Comment: I just found this and it was the problem - unfortunately I did not own the object, so I had to create a DTO with getters/setters and use automapper.

Answer (score 0):

This is a super old question, but I've just had a similar problem where only one of the properties of my model was getting bound, despite the names being correct and them all being strings.

Turned out that my model had private setters, and the only one working was the property which had a public one.

So this is another thing to check. This:

```
public class Model
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public string SecondProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

will only bind `FirstProperty`, and `SecondProperty` will be `null`.

For context, I had private setters because this class just *ended up* being a model. In the beginning it was just the result of a series of an *Introduce Parameter Object* sort of refactorings, and was created automatically by ReSharper, which gave public setters only to those properties that were actually written to later in the code.